# Concurrent Queue Adapter

Tags: c++, concurrency, queue, c++17

There's lots of code out there for basic adapters of `std::deque` to provide a thread-safe queue. I've adopted that, but wanted to provide a relatively full analog to `std::queue`, so I've added the whole set of constructors and `operator=`. The queue works fine. My questions are mainly related to the constructors and `operator=`:

1. Have I applied the correct type traits for identifying whether the constructor will be `noexcept`?
2. I'm using `notify_once` for `push` and `emplace`, and `notify_all` for `operator=` overloads. Is that correct?
3. Because I need to acquire a lock before altering the queue, the constructors have to be written a bit differently from the `std::queue` adapter. For example, the initializer list can't include the data copy/move. Does that code look correct?
4. The conditional `noexcept` syntax I've added for `size` and `empty` looks bizarre. Am I doing that correctly?

Other comments not related to those questions are welcome. One note about the class: I did add some combination methods (e.g., `clear_count_push`) because that is a common combination of calls that I use—such as at program shutdown when I push a close thread semaphore on the queue so that the thread taking work off the queue will know it's time to shut down.

**Note: since posting I've updated this significantly. See https://gist.github.com/rsjaffe/59d22db0649d8276e42aca1061d7c08c for the latest version.**

```cpp
template<typename T, class Container = std::deque<T>> class BlockingQueue {
 public:
   using container_type = Container;
   using value_type = typename Container::value_type;
   using size_type = typename Container::size_type;
   using reference = typename Container::reference;
   using const_reference = typename Container::const_reference;
   static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, value_type>, "container adaptors require consistent types");
   // Constructors: see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/queue
   // These are in same order and number as in cppreference
   /*1*/ BlockingQueue() noexcept(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible_v<Container>){};
   /*2*/ explicit BlockingQueue(const Container& cont) noexcept(
       std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<Container>)
       : queue_{cont}
   {
   }
   /*3*/ explicit BlockingQueue(Container&& cont) noexcept(
       std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<Container>)
       : queue_{std::move(cont)}
   {
   }
   /*4*/ BlockingQueue(const BlockingQueue& other)
   {
      auto lock{std::scoped_lock(other.mutex_)};
      queue_ = other.queue_;
   }
   /*5*/ BlockingQueue(BlockingQueue&& other) noexcept(
       std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<BlockingQueue>)
   {
      auto lock{std::scoped_lock(other.mutex_)};
      queue_ = std::move(other.queue_);
   }
   /*6*/ template<class Alloc, class = std::enable_if_t<std::uses_allocator_v<Container, Alloc>>>
   explicit BlockingQueue(const Alloc& alloc) noexcept(
       std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<Container, const Alloc&>)
       : queue_{alloc}
   {
   }
   /*7*/ template<class Alloc, class = std::enable_if_t<std::uses_allocator_v<Container, Alloc>>>
   BlockingQueue(const Container& cont, const Alloc& alloc) : queue_{cont, alloc}
   {
   }
   /*8*/ template<class Alloc, class = std::enable_if_t<std::uses_allocator_v<Container, Alloc>>>
   BlockingQueue(Container&& cont, const Alloc& alloc) noexcept(
       std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<Container, Container, const Alloc&>)
       : queue_(std::move(cont), alloc)
   {
   }
   /*9*/ template<class Alloc, class = std::enable_if_t<std::uses_allocator_v<Container, Alloc>>>
   BlockingQueue(const BlockingQueue& other, const Alloc& alloc) : queue_(alloc)
   {
      auto lock{std::scoped_lock(other.mutex_)};
      queue_ = other.queue_;
   }
   /*10*/ template<class Alloc,
       class = std::enable_if_t<std::uses_allocator_v<Container, Alloc>>>
   BlockingQueue(BlockingQueue&& other, const Alloc& alloc) noexcept(
       std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<Container, Container, const Alloc&>)
       : queue_(alloc)
   {
      auto lock{std::scoped_lock(other.mutex_)};
      queue_ = std::move(other.queue_);
   }
   // operator=
   BlockingQueue& operator=(const BlockingQueue& other)
   {
      {
         auto lock{std::scoped_lock(mutex_, other.mutex_)};
         queue_ = other.queue_;
      }
      condition_.notify_all();
      return *this;
   }
   BlockingQueue& operator=(BlockingQueue&& other) noexcept(
       std::is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<Container>)
   {
      {
         auto lock{std::scoped_lock(mutex_, other.mutex_)};
         queue_ = std::move(other.queue_);
      }
      condition_.notify_all();
      return *this;
   }
   // destructor
   ~BlockingQueue() = default;
   // methods
   void push(const T& value)
   {
      {
         auto lock{std::scoped_lock(mutex_)};
         queue_.push_back(value);
      }
      condition_.notify_one();
   }
   void push(T&& value)
   {
      {
         auto lock{std::scoped_lock(mutex_)};
         queue_.push_back(std::move(value));
      }
      condition_.notify_one();
   }
   template<class... Args> void emplace(Args&&... args)
   {
      {
         auto lock{std::scoped_lock(mutex_)};
         queue_.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      }
      condition_.notify_one();
   }
   T pop()
   {
      auto lock{std::unique_lock(mutex_)};
      condition_.wait(lock, [this]() noexcept(noexcept(std::declval<Container&>().empty())){
         return !queue_.empty(); 
      });
      T rc{std::move(queue_.front())};
      queue_.pop_front();
      return rc;
   }
   [[nodiscard]] std::optional<T> try_pop()
   {
      auto lock{std::scoped_lock(mutex_)};
      if (queue_.empty())
         return std::nullopt;
      T rc{std::move(queue_.front())};
      queue_.pop_front();
      return rc;
   }
   void clear()
   {
      auto lock{std::scoped_lock(mutex_)};
      queue_.clear();
   }
   [[nodiscard]] auto size() const noexcept(noexcept(std::declval<Container&>().size()))
   {
      auto lock{std::scoped_lock(mutex_)};
      return queue_.size();
   }
   [[nodiscard]] auto clear_count()
   {
      auto lock{std::scoped_lock(mutex_)};
      auto ret = queue_.size();
      queue_.clear();
      return ret;
   }
   auto clear_count_push(const T& value)
   {
      size_type ret;
      {
         auto lock{std::scoped_lock(mutex_)};
         ret = queue_.size();
         queue_.clear();
         queue_.push_back(value);
      }
      condition_.notify_one();
      return ret;
   }
   auto clear_count_push(T&& value)
   {
      size_type ret;
      {
         auto lock{std::scoped_lock(mutex_)};
         ret = queue_.size();
         queue_.clear();
         queue_.push_back(std::move(value));
      }
      condition_.notify_one();
      return ret;
   }
   template<class... Args> auto clear_count_emplace(Args&&... args)
   {
      size_type ret;
      {
         auto lock{std::scoped_lock(mutex_)};
         ret = queue_.size();
         queue_.clear();
         queue_.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      }
      condition_.notify_one();
      return ret;
   }
   [[nodiscard]] bool empty() const noexcept(noexcept(std::declval<Container&>().empty()))
   {
      auto lock{std::scoped_lock(mutex_)};
      return queue_.empty();
   }

 private:
   Container queue_{};
   mutable std::condition_variable condition_{};
   mutable std::mutex mutex_{};
};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   /*9*/ template<class Alloc, class = std::enable_if_t<std::uses_allocator_v<Container, Alloc>>>
   BlockingQueue(const BlockingQueue& other, const Alloc& alloc) : queue_(alloc)
   {
      auto lock{std::scoped_lock(other.mutex_)};
      queue_ = other.queue_;
   }
```

This doesn't look quite right. `queue_ = other.queue;` may cause the allocator from `other.queue` to be used, [depending on the allocator traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/operator%3D).

To ensure correct behavior, we probably need to use the relevant `Container` constructor instead:

```
   /*9*/ template<class Alloc, class = std::enable_if_t<std::uses_allocator_v<Container, Alloc>>>
   BlockingQueue(const BlockingQueue& other, const Alloc& alloc)
   {
      auto lock{std::scoped_lock(other.mutex_)};
      queue_ = Container(other.queue_, alloc);
   }
```

(And the same for `/*10*/`).

---

```
[[nodiscard]] auto size() const noexcept(noexcept(std::declval<Container&>().size()))
[[nodiscard]] auto clear_count()
... etc.
```

We could use `size_type` rather than `auto`.

---

```
[[nodiscard]] auto clear_count()
... etc.
```

Perhaps `count_clear` would better reflect the order that this function does things in. (And the same for the other similar functions).

---

(I'm not very familiar with `noexcept`, so I haven't checked that aspect).

Comment: Interesting. So operator= may result in the allocator being changed to the same as the source allocator. I'll change #9 and #10 to do what you suggest. Thanks.